# Changing images on Bootstrap's Portfolio Item template

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using bootstrap’s template available on https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/portfolio-item/, I am trying to change source of figure by clicking on smaller ones. Here’s what I've tried without success. (Thanks in advance!)

Added id="myImage" on main figure

```
<img class="img-responsive" id="myImage" src="img1.jpg">
```

and onClick="changeImage()" on smaller

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" onClick="changeImage()">
        <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="img2.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

The script function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage() {
        if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'img1.jpg') {
            document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'img2.jpg';
        } else if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'img2.jpg') {
            document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'img1.jpg';
        }
    }
</script>
```

(Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 0):

getElementBYId('onlyIDnoDot') should be the syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage() {
        if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'http://placehold.it/750x500') {
            document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'http://placehold.it/500x300';
        } else if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'http://placehold.it/500x300') {
            document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'http://placehold.it/750x500';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's true...but apparently the problem i have is defining http://placehold.it/750x500 with img1.jpg and http://placehold.it/500x300 with img2.jpg. why doesn't it work like this?

Comment: none, it simply doesn't change the image with local jpgs.

Comment: may be try .jpeg or try png or something

Comment: nothing... it works fine with if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'http://placehold.it/750x500'){document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'img1.jpg';} but not with img1.jpg or jpeg or png or wtv name.

Comment: if thats the case, you must see something in console like img not found

Comment: no error nor warning, really. apparently if i use 'file:///Users/ ... /img1.jpg' it works. the browser is converting the source to a full address. do you know how to avoid it? (thanks!!)

Comment: nope. already tried some of those combinations and it only works with full address. very strange.